# How to Pass data from one view to another in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a view function("View A")  thats gets called first and then I call the my payment gateway which is "paytm payment gateway" it after finishing the transaction calls "View B"

So now what I want is the values that were submitted in the "view A " to be passed to "View B"

Just for the information I'm using Django not Django rest

Sollution that I have tried
I have tried Using Session
#To store value in a session variable
View A:-

```
request.session['message'] = request.POST.get("message")
```

#to retrieve the value from session Variable
View B:-

```
request.session.get('message')
```

Any help or guidance will be great as I have stuck for quite some time now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the session should work, what issue(s) are you having?  Does your payment gateway allow you to attach metadata/additional info to the request that you could then retrieve?

Comment: Am I correct in saying you want to call View A, then the payment gateway, then call View B using information available from the call to View A?
Can you give me an example of what information you are trying to pass between the two views? Is it related to the payment? I'd probably suggest against using a session for any information required between calls to a payment gateway. Instead you should construct some sort of object in the database with that information, then access that object based on information returned by the payment gateway, like a pre-known piece of meta info like an order number

Comment: @MarkBarrett the information im trying to pass is the message that I want to store with transaction details that I get from the gateway

Comment: @IainShelvington i havent research about that ....i will check it out

Comment: @SachinRajput What gateway specifically is it? Something like PayPal? What is the message you want to store? The general flow for handling a payment in this would be something like: Collect information to facilitate the payment, like amount, currency etc., generate an order number, save that all to the db, then pass the order number to the gateway in some "meta" field. When the gateway responds, it'll return that "meta" field, which you can then use to lookup the row in the db that has the information you intended to save. For example, PayPal has a "custom" field for this and Stripe "meta"

Comment: @MarkBarrett its  "Paytm payment gateway"

Comment: Looking at their docs, they have a "orderId" field which if you generate, you could do so before you initiate the transaction. You also have a "extendInfo" field which could be used for this purpose.

My suggestion would be to create a row in the DB with information pertaining to this payment, generate an "orderId" or a piece of information for extendInfo and save any other information you want in View A, then when Paytm responds to View B, it *should* return that "orderId" or "extendInfo' which you can then use to lookup that row to get that saved information.

Comment: I'd just overall suggest staying away from sessions like this as it leads to issues with them being cleaned up and could have unintended side effects. The request should be quite stateless.

Comment: @MarkBarrett Actually after you suggested i tried that extendInfo field but I didn't got the data of that field back in response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238360/discussion-between-mark-barrett-and-sachin-rajput).